# Pick every element once from sorted array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have a sorted array and I want to take every element once into an other array

Example:

```
Input:  array[] = { 1,2,2,3,3,5 }
Output: array2[] = { 1,2,3,5 }
```

---

Here is my attempt

```
int db = 0,array2[100];

for(int i = 0;i < k;i++){
    int j = 0;
    for(j = 0;j < db;j++){
        if(array[i] == array2[j]){
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i == j){
        array2[db] == array[i];
        db++;
    }
}
/* PRINT
for(int i = 0;i < db;i++){
    cout<<array2[i]<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;*/
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a standard algorithm [std::unique_copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique_copy) that does exactly this:

```
auto end = std::unique_copy(std::begin(array), std::end(array), array2);
```

The returned iterator `end` points to one past the last element that is inserted into `array2`, so you can calculate the number of unique elements that were copied like this:

```
auto num = std::distance(array2, end);
```

---

I would recommend using `std::vector` instead of arrays anyway, and then you don't have to worry about computing the number of copied unique elements. In case you use a `vector` the 3rd argument to the algorihtm would be `std::back_inserter(vec)`.

Answer (score 1):

We can't give you an answer about what happened to your code if we don't know what k is.

But generally, if you want unique values from a sorted array, the quick way to do it is just employ the set.

```
#include <set>
```

then `set<int, greater<int> > s1;`

```
for (int i: array) s1.insert(i);
```

this will only add unique value in the new vector in increasing order.

Comment: To construct a `set` from a container you would just use the range constructor like `std::set<int> s1(std::begin(array1), std::end(array1));`.